# Why is bios time in UTC 'recommended' for Linux?

Tags: linux, time, synchronization, bios

Very often when seeing setup guides and similar, it is written that syncing to bios/rtc time in UTC/GMT is 'recommended' but there is never a reason given and googling so far did not help me find one. I guess the most likely reason here is tradition and that it might confuse the odd sysadmin or program that somehow relies on bios time being in utc?

Comment: The question should be asked the other way around: UTC is the obvious default; why would setup guides recommend using anything else?

Answer (score 4):

Machine firmwares don't keep track of what timezone they are in, so is you want them to track what the absolute current time is, you must pick some standard, and there really isn't any other obvious choice for that beside UTC. If different people chose different standards then either the machine firmware would have to provide an interface to tell the OS which one is in use, or provide an interface to the time in a "standard" time zone — and we're back to UTC.

What's worse, many timezones in the world don't have a fixed offset away from UTC: they have two different fixed offsets from UTC depending on what time of the year it is. The machine firmware would have to know those rules and apply them. For every timezone you could conceivably want to use! And those rules change from time to time! If the machine firmware doesn't track and apply those rules, but yet you still want to keep the firmware time in the local (variable-offset) timezone, the OS must compensate by applying a hack — but then it cannot be reliably determined whether or not the hack is currently applied. It's just not tenable.

So... UTC FTW. Machine firmware is low level. Does it really have any reason to need to know the local time in the place where it's running?

Comment: Actually, some machine firmwares _do_ track timezones.  [Timezone information is part of the API specification for EFI firmwares.  It's the actual RTC _hardware_ that is the problem.](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/keeping-time-in-dos.html)

Answer (score 0):

Setting timezone to something other than UTC is done by (some) to solve problems where one system may not have complete timezone support.  The advice as such evolved from a mindset by some that there's only one system being booted, and **that** will set the timezone.  You can read one of those discussions in [Debian #343645
initscripts: Please work around util-linux's broken clock-setting](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=343645)